# Simplificar código que contiene un .class

Tags: java, android

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createOnclickViews();
}

private void createOnclickViews() {
    TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    TextView family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family);
    TextView colors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colors);
    TextView phrases = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phrases);

   numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NumbersActivity.class);
           startActivity(numbersIntent);
       }
   });

    family.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent familyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FamilyActivity.class);
            startActivity(familyIntent);
        }
    });

    colors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent colorsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ColorsActivity.class);
            startActivity(colorsIntent);
        }
    });

    createListener(phrases);
}

private void createListener(final TextView vie) {
    vie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,vie.getClass());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

El método `createListener` provoca un error en la aplicación, me gustaría solucionarlo para poder llamar a `numbers`, `family`, `color` y `phrases` con el mismo método sin tener que repetir tanto código, (Actualmente solo lo ejecuta con `phrases` para comprobar su funcionamiento).

**Dentro de `createListener`, utilizo `vie.getClass()`, lo cual no se si es correcto, lo utilizo como sustituto a  `PhrasesActivity.class` ¿Es correcto?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias, añado el resultado en base a tu solucion:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createOnclickViews();
}

private void createOnclickViews() {
    TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    TextView family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family);
    TextView colors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colors);
    TextView phrases = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phrases);

    createListener(numbers,NumbersActivity.class);
    createListener(family,FamilyActivity.class);
    createListener(colors,ColorsActivity.class);
    createListener(phrases,PhrasesActivity.class);

}

private void createListener(TextView numbers, final Class loayoutViewClass) {
    numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent inten = new Intent(MainActivity.this,loayoutViewClass);
            startActivity(inten);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: No es necesario o requerido que agregas la implementación completa de una respuesta en SOes. Si quieres demostrar como implementaste la solución, se recomienda que aceptas una respuesta y luego __editas__ tu pregunta, agregando al fin la solución. La utilidad de las publicaciónes luego se realiza por votos (las flechas a la izquierda), y eso tambien vale para preguntas, así no pierdes nada. :)

Answer (score 4):

Para simplificar los eventos del CLICK en un item (en tu caso TextView) tienes que implementar **OnClickListener** a tu **CLASE** por lo que quedaría:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
```

Luego agregas el método que te pide:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

Agregar el ClickListener al elemento (en tu caso al TextView) poniendo un ejemplo en el onCreate que es lo recomendable:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ....Código
     TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
     numbers.setOnClickListener(this);
 ....Código
```

Ya por último te encargas de especificar cada ID:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.numbers) /* Dio clic en NUMBERS */
    {
        ..HAZ ALGO
    }
}
```

De esta forma estarás usando la INTERFAZ que por defecto ya trae y reduces algo de código, además de que sigues el estándar.

**Te lo dejo como quedaría**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView numbers;
    TextView family;
    TextView colors;
    TextView phrases;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
        numbers.setOnClickListener(this);
        family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family);
        family.setOnClickListener(this);
        colors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colors);
        colors.setOnClickListener(this);
        phrases = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phrases);
        phrases.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id)
        {
            case R.id.numbers:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.family:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,FamilyActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.colors:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ColorsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.phrases:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,PhrasesActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No es correcto. El intento necesita una clase de una actividad, y `vie` es un TextView **dentro** de una clase de actividad. Vas a tener que inventar otro criterio de distinguir entre las actividades que llamas desde tus `TextView`.

Sin caer en ciencia de cohete, lo más factible probablemente sería:

```
private void createOnclickViews() {
    TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    TextView family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family);
    TextView colors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colors);
    TextView phrases = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phrases);

    createListener(numbers, NumbersActivity.class);
    createListener(family, FamilyActivity.class);
    createListener(colors, ColorsActivity.class);
    createListener(phrases, PhrasesActivity.class);
}

private void createListener(final TextView vie, Class clazz) {
    vie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, clazz);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```